# ASP.NET Page Life Cycle: How Page.ProcessRequest executes events and internal methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, page-lifecycle

To understand ASP.NET page life cycle, I believe understanding Page.ProcessRequest method is more important because ProcessRequest method calls all events and methods for a page. 
Does anyone know at code level how event and methods calls are arranged in Page.ProcessRequest method (**reflector code will also do**)?

Comment: You might find the answers to [this question][1] useful too.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754624/step-through-net-framework-source-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the below order of methods that get runs from ProcessRequest

```
The processRequest() method cycles through the page's life cycle in the order listed below.

Methods                 Description
Page_Init                   Page Initialization
LoadViewState           View State Loading
LoadPostData            Postback Data Processing
Page_Load                   Page Loading
RaisePostDataChangedEvent   PostBack Change Notification
RaisePostBackEvent          PostBack Event Handling
Page_PreRender          Page Pre Rendering Phase
SaveViewState           View State Saving
Page_Render                 Page Rendering
Page_Unload Page            Unloading
```

For more information please see on link http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/performance/page-life-cycle-asp.aspx

Comment: this is something which is already available. I want in depth knowledge about how above methods are executed in ProcessRequest method. In short decompiled code of ProcessRequest method.

Comment: @ParagM in that case I would suggest a tool from JetBrians called DotPeek, hope that works for you